# Is $U(1)$ a normal subgroup of $U(2)$ and does the question even make sense?

Tags: matrices, group-theory, lie-groups, normal-subgroups, quotient-spaces

I have been wondering whether $U(1)$, defined as the group of complex phases (edit for clarity: I mean complex numbers of unit absolute value, such as $e^{i\alpha}$ with $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$) with multiplication as group operation, is a normal subgroup of $U(2)$, defined as the group of $2\times 2$ unitary matrices. With these definitions I would say that $U(1)$ isn't even a subgroup of $U(2)$, let alone normal. However, it is isomorphic to many subgroups of $U(2)$ such as:

- $A=\begin{bmatrix} e^{i\alpha} & 0 \\ 0 & e^{i\alpha} \\ \end{bmatrix}$
- $B=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & e^{i\alpha} \\ \end{bmatrix}$

Now $A$ is normal in $U(2)$ while $B$ is not. I am not particularly surprised that normality isn't preserved by isomorphism, but then I can only answer to questions like "Is $A$ (or $B$) normal in $U(2)$?".

What happens to the quotient space? Since $B$ is not normal then I think $U(2)/B$ is not a group, however $U(2)/A$ can be. Can you help me to find the manifold underlying these quotient spaces/quotient groups? Shouldn't the quotient be the same if I change a group to an isomorphic one?

Comment: What is a complex phase?

Comment: As you've observed, the structure of a coset space $A / B$ depends not only on the isomorphism types of $A$ and $B$ but on the actual subset $B \subseteq A$. What *is* true is that if $B$ and $B'$ are *conjugate* subgroups in $A$, then $A / B$ and $A / B'$ have the same structure. In particular, if one of $B$ and $B'$ are normal, so is the other, in which case $A / B \cong A / B'$.

Comment: As for identifying $U(2) / A$, do you know how to identify the quotient of $GL(n, \Bbb R)$ by the group of nonzero scalar matrices? (Or perhaps a little easier is $GL_+(n, \Bbb R)$ by the positive scalar matrices.)

Comment: @Travis Can you provide a link on that? My usual strategy to identify a quotient space $X/Y$ is finding a vector space on which $X$ acts transitively and a vector for which $Y$ is a stabilizer, then $X/Y$ is identified with the entire vector space.

Comment: @Joanpemo I've edited the question for clarity.

Comment: @goldrunout Thank you very much.

Comment: That's generally a fine strategy, provided we replace *vector space* with *set* (though often the set has additional structure, e.g., a natural topology, compatible with the action of $X$). For example $U(2) / U(1)$ (where $U(1) = A$ here) is certainly not a vector space.

Comment: The idea in the case I mention is that we can factor $GL_+(n, \Bbb R)$ as the direct product $SL(n, \Bbb R) \times \Bbb R_+$, via the map $A \mapsto ((\det A)^{-1/n} A, (\det A)^{1 / n})$.

Comment: @Travis you are of course right, I was thinking of something else. However, then can you help me to find $U(2)/A$ and $U(2)/B$?

Comment: For example I was thinking that maybe $U(2)$ acts transitively on $S3$ (does it?) and $B$ is the stabilizer of point $(1,0,0,0)$ so I could identify $U(2)/B$ with $S3$ but $S3$ can have group structure, while $B$ is not normal in $U(2)$ therefore I am confused...

Comment: A much simpler example of the normality thing is the group of symmetries of the square, which has five subgroups that are cyclic of order two, but only one of these five subgroups is normal.

Comment: I thought $U(2)/A\cong SU(2)$ but I'm not quite sure

Comment: Actually, it's $PU(2)$, the "projective" unitary group

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Yes you are right.