# Lie group isomorphism between U(2)/U(1) and SU(2)

Tags: lie-groups, group-isomorphism, unitary-matrices

I know that $SU(2)$ is diffeomorphic to 3-sphere $S^3$. And, I know that $U(2)/U(1)$ is diffeomorphic to $S^3$. I would like to know if there is an Lie group isomorphism between $U(2)/U(1)$ and $SU(2)$ in the sense that it is a diffeomorphic (bijective and smooth) and it is a group homomorphism.

Appreciate.

Comment: How do you see $U(1)$ as a subgroup of $U(2)$?

Comment: As in the question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1645800/is-u1-a-normal-subgroup-of-u2-and-does-the-question-even-make-sense

Comment: This appear in the books of physics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, they are not isomorphic. The group $U(2)/U(1)$ is (assuming that you see $U(1)$ as $\{e^{i\theta}\operatorname{Id}\mid\theta\in\Bbb R\}$) the [projective unitary group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_unitary_group) $PU(2)$, which is isomoprphic to $SU(2)/\{\pm\operatorname{Id}\}$, but not it $SU(2)$.